# Too few arguments for PlaySound

Tags: c

```
PlaySound("uuuuuu.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME
```

This is my code and when I try to execute and run it my compiler says this:

Too few arguments to function PlaySound

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From you questions it seems that you're running too fast! slow down and learn the basics before jumping into graphical interfaces and AUDIO VIDEO Applications

Comment: This question does not show the "minimal understanding" that SO requires.

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors:

```
PlaySound("uuuuuu.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME
                      ^                    ^
                      |                    |____ ");" missing
                      |_____ This ')' confuses the compiler
```

Change the `PlaySound` call to the following (please refer to this page for Windows Dev Center examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
PlaySound(TEXT("uuuuuu.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) expects more arguments. You missed the parenthesis. Try this

```
PlaySound(TEXT("uuuuuu.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Comment: @FiddlingBits Tanks. it's just the reference who says that :p

Comment: I totally missed that when I looked at the reference.

Comment: @FiddlingBits The man is running too fast. we have alot of experience than him and we still at the console. he's almost going to fail.

Comment: That's true.  If you don't immediately spot the syntax error in the OP's question, you're a rookie. lol